# Не работает регулярное выражение( "((?U)^(\\w+))" ) для поиска слов

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно найти все логины в тексте.

`String regex = "((?U)^(\\w+))";` не работает, находит только логин в 1 строке.

```
Login;Name;Email
ivanov;Ivan Ivanov;ivanov@mail.ru
петров;Петр Петров;petrov@google.com
obama;Barack Obama;obama@google.com
bush;Джордж Буш;bush@mail.ru
```

Comment: `String regex = "(?Um)^\\w+";` или `"(?Um)^[^\\s;]+"`

Answer (score 0):

Есть более простой способ не применяя регулярок.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "Login;Name;Email\n" +
            "ivanov;Ivan Ivanov;ivanov@mail.ru\n" +
            "петров;Петр Петров;petrov@google.com\n" +
            "obama;Barack Obama;obama@google.com\n" +
            "bush;Джордж Буш;bush@mail.ru";

    String[] split = text.split("\n");
    for (String s : split) {
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(";")));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Если весь текст считывается в одну строковую переменную, можно заставить `^` находить все позиции после перехода на новую строку с помощью `Pattern.MULTILINE` или `(?m)`:

```
String regex = "(?Um)^\\w+";
```

Заметьте, что скобки вокруг всего шаблона не нужны. См. [демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/907kcU/1).

Если вы хотите найти любые символы от начала строки до первого `;`, используйте

```
String regex = "(?Um)^[^\\s;]+";
```

Шаблон `[^\\s;]+` найдёт 1 и более символов, отличных от `;` и пробельных символов в начале строки.

См. [демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/907kcU/2).